# ImageView on mapActivity

Tags: android, imageview, mapactivity

I made a little app with a map for learning.
Over the map I added a textView with actual position upgrading.. 
After some problems I did it with a such layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_location"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txt_location"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_name" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I would add an imageView for showing gps status (focused, enabled, disabled).
I added the imageView under the textView, but I don't see anything.
After some try I'm asking why.

ps:
If I put imageVIew in a LinearLayout (before the map) I see linearLaout (in black for es.) over the map, and I still can't see image but, eventually, only the background if setted.
It's not my goal to add a linear layout, but also in this way I can't see image.

I created image by -> new image asset -> launcher icon (legacy only) clip-art (android logo) -> mo effects. 
than I added it by reference in the imageView.

Comment: Hi @Marco,
Can you post the code on how your tried adding image view under text view.

Comment: I posted the entire layout as it is. (edited post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I don't know if it's usual, 
but adding ImageView from design window, it code Imageview as I posted.
Searching around I found similar situations and I found that correct way to show image over MapFragment is make a change to default code of ImageVIew:

from:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_name" />
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/img_name" />
```

I don't know if I do something wrong with inserting new ImageView,
but hope this could help people that do as me.